# Is the current faceted search effective for SEO?

Tags: 7, search, views

Seems that the url generated by faceted items are not good for SEO (unfriendly to search engines) eg. I have a facet that transforms the url to this format : http://localhost/mysite/property-for-sale/residential-sale?f[0]=field_property_type%3A71

I don't know how i can make it more friendly to search engines as this is automatically generated by the faceted links...

any suggestions, is this possible with the current version of facet search apis?

Answer (score 0):

There is a module for it: [Facet API Pretty Paths](https://www.drupal.org/project/facetapi_pretty_paths). But I didn't try it yet.

Here is a quote about it (from the module's project page):

> Enables pretty paths for searches with [Facet API](https://www.drupal.org/project/facetapi). You will likely use this module in combination with either [Search API](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api) or [Apache Solr Search Integration](https://www.drupal.org/project/apachesolr).